# Using alt codes in Java

Tags: java, string, swing, awt, alt

So I was wondering if there's a way to add alt code characters (♥♣☺☻) into a string in java?

Like `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is a heart: ♥");`

Comment: did you try this statement?

Comment: yes, it showed a box that comes up when a website can't read a character

Comment: i think there's some `\u` escape sequence that you can use

Comment: @SamIam could you give an example in a JOptionPane or System.out.print ?

Comment: try System.out.print("\u9827");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What wrong with what you have?

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is a heart: ♥");
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use the Unicode versions of the ALT codes to show them:

[image]

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I \u2665 you");
```

As we see in comment by @Donald2000 using unicode though would be the better option

**Reference:**

- http://unicode.org/charts/charindex.html

Comment: I'd argue that using Unicode literals is the best idea, since that makes the source files properly compilable on all possible target systems by keeping to ASCII in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine for me too.

The problems is probably in your project settings.
The "project source code encoding" should be UTF-8.

You can change this in NetBeans: 
right click on the project name , **Properties**, **Sources**, **Encoding**: **UTF-8**

Or if you use **maven**  in the **pom.xml**:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```